# How to a create a "localhost:1000/something/..." basically an add on to "something" using app.get node.js

Tags: node.js

How would I use an app.get function to create a new add on to that `/something/` I already have the

```
app.use("/web", authModule);
```

That's my case.. I'm using "web" instead of something. I want to use app.get to make an add on to other page that will be `/web/on_call` how exactly would I get this to work where the page would work (the page doesn't have to display anything, I just want it to not break?)

Here's an example of an app.get function for the `web,` but I'm not sure how to just create a new page...

```
app.get("/web/users", function(req, res) {
    var users = app.models.users.model('User');
    users.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, user_result){
        res.render("users_list", { users : user_result });  
    });
});
```

I do not think I need all of the stuff inside of that function, I just want the page to display. Thank you.

Comment: I think what you are looking for `app.get("/web/users?", function(req, res) {` thats if I understood the question.

Comment: The only thing required in that function to render a page is `res.render(<view>, <model>);`

Comment: @sbarow I'm just looking how to create another /web/...

Comment: it's pretty straight forward  you have it all there

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said in the comments its pretty straight forward, try this...

```
app.get("/web/on_call", function(req, res) {
    res.send("something");
});
```

Comment: Why not use res.partial() ?

Comment: I assumed he was working with express 3.. res.partial was removed in that version https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x